# how to clean up table data in Google Sheet IMPORTHTML?

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

I want to import a table of nuclear power output from [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Атомная_энергетика_по_странам](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC).

For some reason, the second col has the number duplicated, eg

```
<td><span style="display: none; speak: none;">000935</span>
935</td>
```

Is there a way to affect the work of IMPORTHTML() to get only the first child of `<td>`?

Similarly, in the second table, last column, Google Sheet extracts this:

`British Nuclear Fuels (англ.)русск.`

I want to remove the texts `(англ.)` and `русск.`

The text I need is again in the first child of `<td>`:

```
<td><a href="//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Nuclear_Fuels" class="extiw" title="en:British Nuclear Fuels">British Nuclear Fuels</a>
<span style="font-size:95%; position: relative; top: .4em">&nbsp;<span class="ref-info" title="на английском языке" style="font-size:85%; cursor:help; color:#888;">(англ.)</span>
</span><span class="link-ru" style="font-size:80%; margin-left:-1.7em; position: relative; top: -.4em;"><a href="/w/index.php?title=British_Nuclear_Fuels&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="British Nuclear Fuels (страница отсутствует)">русск.</a></span></td>
```

Also, I'd like to clean up bracketed references from col headings, eg `[7]`

Answer (score 1):

- The reason the numbers are duplicated is because they use the ~ wiki template for the purpose of sorting

  `| {{~|001627}}1 627`
- the new better way to sort is: https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Sorting#Specifying_a_sort_key
- I was able to clean with formulas, eg

   `source          cleaned        halved    check
   101240102 709   101240102709   102709    FALSE`

Using these formulas:

- cleaned: `=REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(source,"0"),"^0+| ","")`
- halved: `=replace(cleaned,1,len(cleaned)/2,"")`
- check: `=cleaned=concat(halved,halved)`

A few values don't check out, but the difference between the two halves is small, so that's ok